# Conditional rendering of React component if json key exists

Tags: reactjs, components, conditional-statements

I am trying to conditionally render a component with bad results. I have read many tutorials and Stack Overflow questions but I can't get this work. Could you help me?

The conditional component is a data visualization geographical map which should be rendered only when a fetched json file has "code" key. In other words I have dozens of jsons and some of them include geo map information but not all. I have been trying boolean and different kind of ternary operators in jsx but every time when mapless item is clicked in sidebar React tries to render **Map** child component and gives an error that "code" (key) is undefined. What could be reason for that? Below is my code:

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [product_id, setProduct_id] = useState(13);
  const [mapCode, setMapcode] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/sidebar")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setItems(data);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/data/${product_id}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setFiles(data);
        if ("code" in data[0]) setMapcode(1);
        else setMapcode(0);
        console.log(mapCode);
      });
  }, [product_id]);

 function HandleSelection(e) {
    setProduct_id(e);
  }
```

Inside useEffect if fetched product data includes "code" key I change **mapCode** every time an item (product) is clicked in sidebar. console.log(mapCode) gives right kind of results.

Below is the essential code inside **return()** of App.js. There are couple of ways I have tried to get the conditional rendering work.

```
<div className="col-6">
    <Files files={files} />
</div>
<div className="col-3">
         
    {/*Boolean(mapCode) && <Map files={files} />*/}
    {/*mapCode === true && <Map files={files} />*/}
    mapCode === true ? <Map files={files} /> : <div>No map</div>

</div>
```

I have been wondering if useEffect is the right place to use setMapcode(0) and setMapcode(1)?

Answer (score 0):

First you should set a boolean value to `isMapCode` instead of a number:

```
const [isMapCode, setIsMapcode] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`/data/${product_id}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setFiles(data);
      setIsMapcode(data[0].code !== undefined);
    });
}, [product_id]);
```

Therefore you should check its value inside a scope (`{}`):

```
<div className="col-3">
  {isMapCode ? <Map files={files} /> : <div>No map</div>}
</div>
```

Notice that you don't need another state for it, you can check your `files` state:

```
const isMapCodeAvailable = data[0].code !== undefined;
<div className="col-3">
  {isMapCodeAvailable ? <Map files={files} /> : <div>No map</div>}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I followed the first way of yours `setIsMapcode(data[0].includes("code"));` and got an error: _Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): data[0].includes is not a function_. By the second way `const isMapCodeAvailable = files[0].includes("code");` I got _TypeError: files[0] is undefined_. Somehow `files[0]` in not available. I wrote `const isMapCodeAvailable = files[0].includes('code');` to the beginning of function App() after the states declarations. Was it the right place?

Comment: You don't need to copy-paste the solution, just understand the concept. I don't know how your data looks like.

Comment: The main problem with your code that you didn't use scope inside JSX `{}` and I think `if ("code" in data[0])` does data[0] is an array? Or you checking if the key exists

Comment: I thought `data[0]` is an array, you just can do `data[0].code !== undefined` or `"code" in data[0]` as you done